# TSQL : Any efficient way to insert data in between range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In my SQL Server database, I have a table like this :

```
counter, value
12345, 10.1
12370, 10.5
12390, 9.7
12405, 10.1
12510, 12.3
```

Let's assume that I input a value of 5. I need to fill in the data between the first record and second record by increment of 5 in the counter column.

For example using Record 1 and Record 2, here are the additional data needs to be inserted into the table.

```
12345, 10.1 --> Record 1
12350, 10.1
12355, 10.1
12360, 10.1
12365, 10.1
12370, 10.5 --> Record 2
```

Other than using a database cursor to loop through each record in the table and then select the MIN counter after Record 1, is there any other way that I can achieve it with less I/O overhead ? I just need to insert additional counter between the range based on the input parameter.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: I smell an XY problem here. Can I ask "Why" are you trying to do this before answering?

Comment: Why you want to insert records in between, instead try to write your SQL statement in such a way which produces your required output, you can user sorting statements for that.

Comment: It is for some calculation purpose. The formula given by the user needs to get the average value for the duration. 

Since the data point only capture by the system only if changes in value occurs. Using the existing data points, the average is incorrect. So I need to fill in the gap then only calculate the average.

Comment: do you want to be able to fill N records between any two given data points ?

Comment: yeah, I want to take the value from Record 1, repeat it till Record 2. The logic I have currently is to take counter from Record 1 + input parameter and the counter should not exceed the next counter value here - SELECT MIN(Counter) FROM Table WHERE Counter > Record1-Counter. Just keep incrementing using a cursor. My method invoked a lot of I/O.

Basically, I am using 2 tables. First table contain the original data and the second table is the populated one with numbers in between.

Comment: Why do you not calculate how many data points you *would* have to fill in, and multiply the `value` by that number, as you sum up the numbers to calculate the average? Why do you need to physically instantiate the extra rows?

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to compute a weighted average, there's no need to *create* these rows. You can just work out how many rows you *would* have added and use that information to calculate the average. E.g.:

```
declare @t table (counter int not null, value decimal(19,4) not null)
insert into @t(counter, value) values
(12345, 10.1),
(12370, 10.5),
(12390, 9.7 ),
(12405, 10.1),
(12510, 12.3)

declare @gap int
set @gap = 5

;With Numbered as (
    select counter,value,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY counter) as rn
    from @t
), Paired as (
    select n1.counter,n1.value,
         (n2.counter - n1.counter)/@gap as Cnt --What do we do for the last row?
    from Numbered n1
            left join
        Numbered n2
            on
                n1.rn = n2.rn - 1
)
select SUM(value*COALESCE(Cnt,1))/SUM(COALESCE(Cnt,1)) from Paired
```

Where as you can (hopefully) see, I've currently decided that the last row counts as just 1, but anything else *could* be done there also.

Comment: Hmm ... trying to understand your approach. For my situation, the data points between Record 1 and Record 2 will change the average value. Using my table as an example, if I fill in the gap between Rec 1 ( 12345, 12350, 12355, 12360, 12365, 12370 will have value similar to Rec 1 which is 10.1 ) and Rec 2 ( value 10.5 ), my average is 10.167 compared to (Record 1 + Record 2) / 2 = 10.3

Comment: And, if you just use those first two rows to populate `@t`, you will indeed get a result of `10.167`. The `Numbered` CTE just works out the correct order of the rows. The `Paired` CTE that joins adjacent rows and works out how many rows would have been between them (e.g. for rows 1 and 2, it takes `12370 - 12345` and divides it by `@gap`, `5`, to get 5 - there should be 5 copies of row 1 used in the final result. It may help if you replace my final `SUM` expression with just a `SELECT * from Paired` to see what that CTE is computing.

Answer (score 0):

a recursion should work as well:

```
;WITH 
Initial AS (SELECT COUNTER,value FROM yourtable),
maxvalue AS (SELECT MAX(COUNTER) Mvalue FROM Initial),
 recur AS (
     SELECT COUNTER, value FROM yourtable 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT counter+5,value FROM recur r WHERE COUNTER+5< (SELECT Mvalue FROM maxvalue)
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Initial o WHERE o.COUNTER=r.COUNTER+5)
 )
 SELECT * FROM recur ORDER BY COUNTER
```

just replace 'yourtable' with the name of your table

Comment: Hey Jayvee, your proposal works great but it only applicable for the first 2 records. Nothing happen after that. I try to modify your script to loop through the entire table but it seems not design to do it this way.

Comment: I changed to include the whole table in the recursion (just change view first2 within recur to table yourtable. Still it's meant to fill the gaps only between rows 1 and 2. If you need to fill other gaps, you may need to adapt view first2 to the boundaries of the gap to be filled.

Comment: Hi Jayvee, thanks for your effort. I think it won't help me much if I need to change the TOP 2 in multiple query and I have no idea how many total records in the table. currently, i am using the same concept but just in a cursor form and also writing more codes.

Comment: do you need to fill the gaps between 2 rows or all the gaps in the table?

Comment: Hi Jayvee, all the gaps. Actually, I have a working solution using cursor. Just looking at different alternative to improve it. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: I changed it to fill all the gaps and renamed the view to Initial so you don't get confused by the name. Try it now please.

Answer (score 0):

Filling gaps with values is usually a problem best answered using a `Numbers` table (a table with a single int column containing numbers from 1 to some sufficiently large number):

```
declare @n1 int = 12345, @n2 int = 12370, @step int = 5
select @n1 + (n * @step)
from numbers
where n < (@n2 - @n1) / @step
```